# MySQL- How to query to get rows between certain years

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get back rows that are between year ranges, such as from 0-5 years, 5-10 years, 10-15 etc.

So far, I've only been able to product between 0-5 but need some help on querying between 5-10 years etc.

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE start_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 YEAR)
```

I've tried using the BETWEEN function, but could be using it incorrectly. Open to suggestions.

I'm not a fan of hard coding values in for the dates because I don't want to go back every few years and change it.

Comment: be careful with BETWEEN because of the equality comparison on both ends of the range.  typically with DATE ranges, we use comparisons `>=` and `<` such that the equality is on only one end of the range. That's so a row that is on the boundary doesn't get included in two different ranges. (It makes the ranges overlap.) It really depends on the use case, whether we want to report a user with start_date exactly 5 years ago in *both* 0-5 range and 5-10 range.

Comment: 0-5 first interval, 5-10 second interval, where do you need the value 5 to be placed...in the first range or in second range?

Comment: @krishnaaryal: great question. because (typically) we don't want any overlap in date ranges... basically asking... for a row that is on the boundary between two ranges, which range should it fall into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `start_date` is DATE datatype (not DATETIME or TIMESTAMP)

five years ago up to today

```
 WHERE start_date >  DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -5 YEAR
   AND start_date <= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL  0 YEAR
```

ten years ago up to five years ago

```
 WHERE start_date >  DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -10 YEAR
   AND start_date <= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -5  YEAR
```

Comment: Feel free to use `CURR_DATE` in place of `DATE(NOW())` and the `DATE_SUB` function in place of the `+ INTERVAL` syntax, will get equivalent results. Also, depending on how the ranges are defined, we could flip the equality comparison down to the lower end of the range, so comparisons are `>=` and `<`, but if we did that in this case, it would leave rows for "today" out of "0-5" range.

Comment: If start_date is DATETIME or TIMESTAMP datatype (including a time component), resist the temptation to wrap start_date in a DATE() function. Instead, adjust the expressions that specify the begin and end of the range. More complex expressions on the range definition side only get evaluated once, at the beginning of the statement. A `DATE()` function wrapped around `start_date` would get evaluated for *every* row in the table, the return from that is then compared to the static range boundary values. More opportunity for better performance (index range scan) when predicates are on bare columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BETWEEN`.

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE (start_date BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 YEAR))
```

and then for your next interval:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE (start_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 YEAR) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 YEAR))
```

Comment: note that this has potential for rows on an interval boundary to satisfy conditions for both intervals. for date range intervals, we typically use `>=` and `<` comparisons, so the equality is on just one end of the range. or we can do comparisons.  or `>` and `<=`, again, equality is on just one end of the range. (the BETWEEN is equivalent to `>=` and `<=` with equality on both ends of the range)

Comment: That's a good point. Your answer accounts for this, have an upvote. :)

Comment: it really depends on the use case, how to handle rows that are on interval boundaries, whether there should be any "overlap" in the intervals. If we want to use BETWEEN we could game it by subtracting one second so we do `BETWEEN '2017-11-15 00:00:00' AND '2017-11-15 23:59:59'.  But then that makes the assumption that second is the lowest resolution for datetime/timestamp, which isnt necessarily the case in MySQL any longer (up to six decimal digits for seconds now). We've got a one second no mans land between the end of one range and start of another.

Answer (score 0):

0 - 5

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE
start_date BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 YEAR) AND CURDATE();
```

5 - 10

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE
start_date BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 YEAR) AND (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 YEAR);
```

10 - 15

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE
start_date BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 15 YEAR) AND (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 YEAR);
```